# how can i limit number of ticks in jqplot (line plot)?

Tags: jqplot, axis

I'm using JQPLOT to create graphs. But I have a lot of data for the x-axis. Now, i need to limit the number of ticks. I'm using numberTicks for this but doesn't work.

```
xaxis: {
                numberTicks:15,
                max: x_limits.max,
                min: x_limits.min,
                renderer:$.jqplot.CategoryAxisRenderer,
                rendererOptions:{tickRenderer:$.jqplot.CanvasAxisTickRenderer},
                tickOptions:{formatString:'%#m/%#d/%Y'}
            },
```

I'm using CategoryAxisRenderer. When i use DateAxisRenderer, it works. -.-

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT** (wrong answer) It doesn't work because it takes account of your minimal and maximal xaxis values. Try to remove them to take into account the "numberTicks" options (or just specify one of them but I'm not sure it will be correct)

**EDIT2** : You have to remove the renderer and rendererOptions from the xaxis part :

```
xaxis:{
 //renderer:$.jqplot.CategoryAxisRenderer,
 //rendererOptions:{tickRenderer:$.jqplot.CanvasAxisTickRenderer},
 max: 40,
 min: 1,
 numberTicks: 5,
}
```

Please see a working example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/AnthonyLeGovic/LkXXu/1/) with 5 ticks.